# onclick display the code entered along with database without using iframe( just like when we post a news it appears in facebook)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, user-interface

I am trying to display the content just like in facebook.but i dint get it.i used iframe.can some one help me with this without using iframe.i want it to get independently ..like if user1 post it must be seperated from user2 ..but i didnt get it using iframe ii just got a linebreak ..
i here by attaching two images for idea sake [facebook layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOWAS.png)
[this is my outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cyhm.png).it would be helpful if u solve ...Thanks in Advance..atleast the working ui would be helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
<body>
<div id = "midle"> 
<div id="posts" > 
<h1>WHAT'S UP?</h1> 
<tr> <form method="POST" action="tryy.php" target="iframe_a" > 
<textarea name="post" rows="5" cols=110" target="iframe_a" ></textarea> 
<td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="POST" ></td> 
</form> 
<iframe width="100%" height="590" src="tryy.php" name="iframe_a"></iframe> 
</div> 
</div> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax.
(replace the iframe with a div that for this example has the id "status")

```
<div id="status"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get(
       'tryy.php',
       function(response){
          $("#status").html(response);
       }
    );
</script>
```

Inserted into your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
<style>
  #status {
    background:#555;
    width: 100%;
    height: 590px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="midle">
    <div id="posts">
      <h1>WHAT'S UP?</h1>
      <tr>
        <form method="POST" action="tryy.php" target="iframe_a">
          <textarea name="post" id="statusBox" rows="5" cols=110  target="iframe_a " ></textarea> 
<td><input id="button" type="submit"  name="submit " value="POST " ></td> 
</form> 
<div id="status"></div>
</div> 
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js "></script>
<script>
function updateStatusList(){
  $.get(
    'tryy.php',
    function(response){
      $("#status").html(response);
    }
  );
}
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateStatusList();
    return false;
});
$("#statusBox").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){ // when return was pressed
    updateStatusList();
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:

Since you are new some hints:

- You should use <!DOCTYPE html> instead.
- Use a closing </body> tag ;)
- Don't use td, tr elements without a table element (and you shouldn't actually use tables at all for layouting)

Comment: hey hi!! Thanx much but can you give me a brief idea about what should be placed in place of that #example..as i am new and i dont even have basic idea about js

Comment: you are welcome, glad I could help. Feel free to accept my post as answer ;)

Comment: Well if it is supposed be be like on facebook you need to bind the $.get onto a keydown event. See this link: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: I updated the post again (textarea has now id statusBox and the javascript below is updated.)

Comment: it is displaying in other tab rather i want it in the same page just below the text area (updating)

Comment: i used your code only #hans but its not working.its like  , when a user posted the  post its not displaying or updating anything,but when i refreshed the page its showing the updated result in new tab :(

Comment: I edited my answer once more. Since somehow my editor automatically trimmed the spaces away in the id strings used in jquery i havn't seen it first after i copied your code. Always make sure that there is no additional space after the id (e.g. $("#element") instead of $("#element ")). Also i added something to the button click event (preventDefault and return false) which both just execute the js but dont submit the form after). If tryy.php (which i dont know the code of) relies on a normal form submission to work you need to either change it or use type="button" instead of type="submit"

Comment: this is my tryy.phpcode    <?php 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['post'])) { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO post (username, post) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_POST['post']."')"; 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { } 
else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; } }$sqli = "SELECT username,post FROM post ORDER BY sno DESC"; 
$result = $conn->query($sqli); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 


echo "<h4>" . $row["username"]."  </h4> ".$row["post"]."<br><br><hr>"; 
}} 
else { 
echo "BE THE FIRST TO POST "; } 
$conn->close(); 
?>

Comment: Does it work now with the changes i made? Again it works for me when i test it ...